# AngularJS: How to update scope variable value in current target during ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

In AngularJS, how do I update a target scope variable in a loop (ng-repeat).

```
<div data-ng-repeat="title in titles">
    {{ title.name }} - {{ quantity }}
    <button type="button" ng-click="addQty(quantity)">Add quantity</button>
    <button type="button" ng-click="subQty(quantity)">Substract quantity</button>
</div>

$scope.quantity = 0;

$scope.addQty = function(index) {
    // I want to update the current Quantity variable, not global one...
    index++;
};

$scope.subQty = function(index) {
    index--;
};
```

Note: I have no control in titles variable since it's from an external JSON file. Modifying the original array would be perfect, but I don't have access.

In jQuery, it's very easy with jQuery(this), but I have no clue how to do it on AngularJS.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Pass in the index and target the array index:

```
ng-click="addQty($index)"
```

And the JS:

```
$scope.addQty = function(index) {
    $scope.titles[index].quantity = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It's not perfectly exactly what I'm looking for, but your hint gave me an idea how to resolve it.